# Unable to create relationship. Incorrect syntax near ACTION

Tags: foreign-keys, relationship

I have two tables:

Table 1 = **ChipsetController**

```
ID int Primary Key
ControllerID int
ChipsetID int
ModelID int
Speed_ID int
NumberOfPorts nvarchar(2)
ConnectionID int
```

Table 2 = **Connection**

```
ID int Primary Key
Connection nvarchar(10)
```

I am trying to join these two tables by
table **Connection** `ID` and table **ChipsetController** `ConnectionID`. When I hit on save, I get confirmation that changes will be made to those two tables. Once I hit yes, I get this message:

**'Connection' table saved successfully
'ChipsetController' table
- Unable to create relationship 'FK_ChipsetController_Connection'.

Incorrect syntax near 'Connection'.
Incorrect syntax near 'ACTION'.**

Any idea? This relationship was established before and use to work fine until I tried to add *Indexes/Keys* to the table **Connection** for Column *Connection* to be *Unique Key*. Once I did that, the relationship broke. I have reverted to the original state and I have now this issue.
I have tried to remove PK from table **Connection** and assign it again but still getting that same error. I am using SQL Server 2019

Answer (score 0):

Connection is a preseverd keyword. Try creating the relationship by script:

```sql
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ChipsetController]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_ChipsetController_Connection] FOREIGN KEY([ConnectionId])
    REFERENCES [dbo].[Connection] ([Id])
    GO
    
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ChipsetController] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_ChipsetController_Connection]
    GO
```